# Android robust threading Architecture? Asynctask vs thread/handler vs service/thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading, service, android-asynctask

Let's say you're designing the threading architecture for a an app -> the primary purpose is that your app will have a lot of tasks that need something done on the background thread, and sometimes a result task on UI thread, or something not (though more times, the result needs to be run on UI thread). For simplicity, let's say the tasks will be stuff like: download a file and display a pop-up, log a user in and go to a different page, process an image and store the result in a database (popular tasks that a lot of apps do)

I've researched a lot about the nuances, but would really like a deep-dive explanation/knowledge on what kind of architecture is better, and what are the considerations.

here are the three models in consideration:

1. AsyncTask model: each operation (like downloading a file and displaying a pop-up) is an AsyncTask, or some derivative of a parent class that abstracts out the common functionalities.
2. Thread/handler model: i always create a `new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());` and each time i need to do a task, i use a thread factory to spin off the task, with the handler on UI thread (or whatever custom handler).
3. Service/Thread model: i use a general `Service` class that is in charge of operations based on some operation code. there's a bunch of `ServiceTask` derivative objects that do certain things, but the `Service` class communicates with each `ServiceTask` when tasks are started/done.

I'm slightly leaning towards going the whole service/threading model, just because i've read some really awkward nuances with AsyncTask/Threads:

- AsyncTask has a `private` `static` `handler`, and if the classloader calls it at the wrong time (such as including a library that uses it before your application does) then all of your `onPostExecute` will happen at the wrong time since your handler was not the main handler
- it's easy to forget to check a bunch of things in the `onPostExecute` such as if there was a config change, or your activity was destroyed, or application was backgrounded/paused when the `onPostExecute` is called (leading to crashes)
- AsyncTask changed its serial/parallel execution behavior on different APIs
- If you went with the Thread/Handler model, on older devices, thread priority is actually incredibly low. i've heard something like there was a priority scale of 1-15 such that your threads automatically get a low priority and if the system was low on resources, your threads would stop running (whereas since services are running independently of your activity the thread priority there is higher?)

What is the best way to design a robust threading architecture that doesn't easily lead to crashes/unexpected behavior while also maintaining good performance ??

Please also let me know in the comments if this question is too vague and if you need actual code (i'm afraid to post code because it would super overbloat the question length more than it already is).

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you will find a one-size fits all approach here.

- Downloading a file? Use [`DownloadManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.html)
- Logging a user in and go to next screen? Probably an AsyncTask would be best.
- Process an image and store it? A `Service` might be a good choice here since you don't want the action to be attached to any particular `Activity`.
- `Handlers` are more tricky, if they are attached to a `Looper` running on a background thread you need to call `quit()` on the `Looper` when you are done with it. Handlers are good when you need to delay an action, `postDelayed()` is great for that. They are also good when you need to communicate back to the UI thread from a background thread.

But yes you are correct that each one has pitfalls as you mentioned. Android is a complex beast and it seems they could have a done a better job preventing developers from shooting themselves in the foot, especially in regards to AsyncTask being called after an Activity is destroyed!

Comment: i think your answer is correct for a code base that is small and relatively manageable by a couple of people, but if there were like ~50 tasks, would you still choose to use a different mechanism for each one? or would you rather develop and use a generic architecture (one that is also easily testable)?

Comment: I doubt a generic architecture will be workable in all situations, Services and threads are very different and meet different needs. If you are worried about crashes you might want to use a safer wrapped AsyncTask class such as one recommended here http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/04/retaining-objects-across-config-changes.html

Answer (score 1):

I was using Java's old school approach by creating a class (I called it ThreadRunner) derived from Java's Thread. A constructor looked like:

```
public ThreadRunner (Object [] params, AbstractCallback callBack) {...}
```

AbstractCallback was a class that was implemnting a single 'onCall' method and was mostly used to notify a calling party about an event such as "execution of a task is completed".

I've used it to get content from Internet and run other time consuming operations. It didn't cause any problems and worked as expected.

However, I've heard many times that AsyncTask is an Android-ish way of doing things like that. I don't know why and do not have any intention to change, since I'm preaching "don't fix it if it's not broken" approach.

I've seen also comments that you'll need to write less code with AsyncTask, but in my approach with traditional Java's Threat the amount of coding was small as well, so I queses it's just a matter of your personal preferences and experience.

In regard of your 3-rd approach - I think you should use it when write a service that runs all the time, listens on requests and never stops. When you just need to execute a single task asynchronously Java Threads or AsyncTask should be used.

Answer (score 1):

I think AsyncTask is a good tool for listed purposes. But it needs to wrap AsyncTask for an easy using. My variant of such wrapping (with a progress indicator) is a following:

Main class AsyncActivity for extending it in application activities:

```
public abstract class AsyncActivity extends Activity{
// Поле нужно обязательно объявить как статическое!
private static AsyncConnect asyncConnect =  null;

protected void runBackgroundTask(String progressInscription, RequestTask task){
    asyncConnect = new AsyncConnect(this, responseListener, progressInscription, task);
    asyncConnect.execute();
}

protected abstract void onBackgroundTaskEnd(boolean result);

@Override
protected void onResume(){
    super.onResume();

    // Перерегистрируем текущий контекст этой формы 
    // для корректной работы слушателя ответа с сервера
    responseListener.registerCurrentContext( this );

    if (asyncConnect != null){
        asyncConnect.onResume(this);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onPause(){
    super.onPause();

    if (asyncConnect != null){
        asyncConnect.onPause();
    }
}

/**
 * Чтобы диалоги не вызывались из устаревшего контекста 
 * и по этой причине не исчезали при повороте экрана,
 * слушателя ответа с сервера необходимо сделать статическим полем класса,
 * в котором должен быть зарегистрирован текущий контекст
 */
private static final OnServerResponseListener responseListener = new OnServerResponseListener(){
    private AsyncActivity context = null;

    @Override
    public void registerCurrentContext(AsyncActivity context){this.context = context; }

    @Override
    public void onResponse(boolean result){
        // Если никакой контекст не был зарегистрирован, ничего не делаем
        if (context == null) return;

        // Освождаем статическое поле для сборщика мусора (но делать это не обязательно!)
        asyncConnect = null;

        // Вызываем колбэк о завершении фоновой задачи
        context.onBackgroundTaskEnd(result); 
    }
};
}
```

Additional class and a pair of interfaces:

```
public class AsyncConnect {
private final Activity context;
private final RequestTask task;
private final String progressInscription;
private final OnServerResponseListener responseListener;
private boolean isDone = false;

private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

public AsyncConnect(Activity context, OnServerResponseListener responseListener,
        String progressInscription, RequestTask task){
    this.context = context;
    this.task = task;
    this.progressInscription = progressInscription;
    this.responseListener = responseListener;

    progressDialog = null;

    isDone = false;
}

public void execute(){
    if (isDone) return;

    new ConnectTask().execute();
}

public void onPause(){
    if (isDone) return;

    if (progressDialog != null){
        if (progressDialog.isShowing()){
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            progressDialog = null;
        } 
    }
}

public void onResume(Activity context){
    if (isDone) return;

    progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show( context, null, (CharSequence)progressInscription, 
        true, false);
}

private class ConnectTask extends AsyncTask<Object, Void, Boolean> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute( ) {
        super.onPreExecute();

        progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show( context, null, 
            (CharSequence)progressInscription, true, false);
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Object... messages) {
        return task.call();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        if (progressDialog != null){
            if (progressDialog.isShowing()){
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                progressDialog = null;
            } 
        }

        // Делаем невозможным повторное использование этого объекта
        isDone = true; 

        responseListener.onResponse(result);
    }
}

}

public interface OnServerResponseListener {
    public void registerCurrentContext(AsyncActivity context);
    public void onResponse(boolean result);
}

public interface RequestTask {
    public boolean call();
}
```

For using AsyncActivity we only need to call runBackgroundTask and implement onBackgroundTaskEnd in the target activity. It's possible to create different kinds of AsyncTask wrappings based on this idea.

Answer (score 1):

You may also check out Needle; it's an open-source, simple but powerful multithreading library for Android. With it you can say things like:

```
Needle.onMainThread().execute(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // e.g. change one of the views
    }
});
```

or

```
Needle.onBackgroundThread().execute(new UiRelatedTask<Integer>() {
    @Override
    protected Integer doWork() {
        int result = 1+2;
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    protected void thenDoUiRelatedWork(Integer result) {
        mSomeTextView.setText("result: " + result);
    }
});
```

- very simple API
- fixed thread pool size
- customizable thread pool size
- supports UI interaction ("do work and then use result on UI thread")
- android 1.5+
- behaves the same on all platform versions

Check it out on GitHub: https://github.com/ZsoltSafrany/needle